# Creating a folder with name and saving the photos I took in the folder. Android App

Tags: android, directory, photo

I want to create a simple application. It will create the folder I entered the name of. I will be able to take photos within the application without leaving the camera application.it will create the folder I entered the name of the photos I took and save it in this folder. Can you help?

How can i create a app like this?

[simple example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ArtO.jpg)

Comment: please help me about this question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.